# Let $h_n $be the number of regions that are created by n mutually overlapping circles in general position in the plane. What is the value of $h_{10}$?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Let $h_n$ be the number of regions that are created by $n$ mutually overlapping circles in general position in the plane. (Note that by general position, we mean that there do not exist three circles with a common point.) What is the value of $h_{10}$?

Comment: Have you tried working out the values of $h_n$ for small values of $n$?

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.